# How to modify a table cells value based on if a checkbox is selected AND anothers cell meets some criteria using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select, html-table, row, each

I have a simple table and I want to create a flag in a td cell if the checkbox in that row is selected and the value of another cell is at least 5.  I can figure out how to do the checkbox and changing the cell but I can't figure out how to use jQuery for the 'AND the other cell is at least 5' part.  Here is my jsfiddle and example of what I have so far.  I would also like for this to recheck anytime the user changes the value of a checkbox. http://jsfiddle.net/silvajeff/yZbQP/

```
$('.mySortedTable').ready(function() {
    $(".mySortedTable input.myChkBox:checked").closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text("Yes"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this:  http://jsfiddle.net/yZbQP/1/

```
$('.mySortedTable').ready(function() {

 $('.mySortedTable').find('tr').each(function(){

  if($(this).find('input.myChkBox').is(':checked') && parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').html(),10) > 4)
    {
        $(this).find('td:eq(2)').text("Yes");
    }
 });
});
```